# How to Download the Image from URL by using Retrofit and set to Notification Icon

Tags: android, image, bitmap, notifications, retrofit2

Here my requirement is, I need to download the bitmap from URL by using Retrofit and need to set to Notification Icon.I tried but i am getting null pointer exception.I dont want to download it to any file or folder. directly i want to use the return bitmap to notification icon.  Pls help where i was wrong

My Code:

```
if (photourl != null) {
if ((photourl.endsWith(".jpg") || photourl.endsWith(".png") || photourl.endsWith(".jpeg") )) {
    if(messageType!=6 && messageType!=7){
      RoundCornerImg RCIMG = new RoundCornerImg();
      bm = RCIMG.getRoundedRectBitmap(getImageBitmap(photourl), 10);

     }else{
       bm = getImageBitmap(photourl);
       }
      photo_flag = true;
       }
  }
```

Get Image Bitmap Method:

```
 private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {

        Call<ResponseBody> call=RetroApiCall.getNotificationImage(url);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
                }else{
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20) {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    return bitmap;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: y aren't u using picasso or glide for this ?

Comment: For picasso and glide we need to spicy the target imageview or else we need to specify the image width and height. it may get the problem if we specify width for multiple devices

Comment: u can use target interface and get the bitmap instead and then do whatever you want with that bitmap

Comment: Can you add any example pls..

Comment: try this
check the answer by me below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the method **getImageBitmap** bitmap wrongly converted. i solved it by following code

```
private void getImageBitmap(String url) {


    Call<ResponseBody> request = RetroApiCall.getNotificationImage(url);

    try {
        downloadFile(request.execute().body());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {

    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    setBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

I got the answer finally!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

private void someMethod() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}

@Override 
public void onDestroy() {  // could be in onPause or onStop
   Picasso.with(this).cancelRequest(target);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```